# Async database query

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I'm just starting out with F# and .Net but after some Googling I didn't find examples of this. I apologize in advance if this is too simple.

I'm trying to query a database and do it asynchronously. For example, I have a function like so:

```
let queryExample name = 
    query {for f in foo do
           where (f.name = name)
           select f.name}
    |> Seq.toList
```

Now, how would I make an async version of this? `query` doesn't return an `Async<'a>` type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer will depend on what you're querying.  Many data sources will expose something like a data context that enables running queries in different ways, but this isn't exposed directly on the `IQueryable` type (and is therefore not something that you can do directly with the result of a `query { ... }` expression.

As an example, if your `foo` is a LINQ-to-SQL `Table<Foo>`, then you can do something like this:

```
let queryExample name =
    let q = 
        query { for f in foo do
                where (f.name = name)
                select f.name }
    let cmd = foo.Context.GetCommand(q)
    async {
        let! reader = Async.AwaitTask (cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        return foo.Context.Translate<Foo>(reader)
    }
```

This will return an `Async<seq<Foo>>`.  If you'll be running lots of queries like this, then it's easy to extract the meat of this into a reusable mechanism.

Comment: I'm using a LINQ-to-EF. Basically, there's no type provider for PostgreSQL or MySQL yet and so I have to use the type provider for the entity framework.

Comment: @GaborSiklos - in the EF case, it might be much easier (assuming you're using EF 6).  I think you could just use the [`ToListAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220258(v=vs.113).aspx) extension method on your query, combined with `Async.AwaitTask`.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm using EF 4.x. What are my options then? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @GaborSiklos Neither EF4 nor 5 support direct async IO methods. The best you can hope for is to wrap them in `async`, which will consume threads. On the other hand, that might be your only chance to get a non-blocking database query.

Answer (score 2):

I use FSharp.Data.Sql with success http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/
Seq.executeQueryAsync

Answer (score 1):

Example below shows an easy syntax for doing this.  Basically just create an async function with a query expression inside and return the result.

```
let data = [ 1; 5; 7; 11; 18; 21]

let getEvenInts = fun (arr : list<int> ) -> async {
    let q = query {        
      for N in arr do
      where (( N % 2 ) = 0)
      select N
    }
    return q
  }

let getOddInts = fun (arr : list<int> ) -> async {
    let q = query {        
      for N in arr do
      where (( N % 2 ) <> 0)
      select N
    }
    return q
  }

let evens = getEvenInts data |> Async.RunSynchronously
let odds = getOddInts data |> Async.RunSynchronously

printfn "Evens: %A Odds: %A" evens odds
```